# Equation of locus of moving point

Tags: implicit-differentiation

How to find the equation of locus of a moving point such that its perpendicular distance from a function $f(x)$ is always $g(x)$?

Comment: Is $f$ differentiable on its domain?

Comment: yeah $f$ differentiable on its domain

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Consider the plot below:

[image]

So, I assumed that $f$ is differentiable on its domain. We know the equation of the line $l$ as follows:

$$l:~~-f'(x_0)x+y+(f'(x_0)x_0-y_0)=A_1x+y+B_1=0$$

Since the distance $d$ between the points $(X,Y)$ and the straight line $l$ is given by $$d=\frac{|A_1X+Y+B_1|}{\sqrt{A_1^2+1}}$$ so it seems that we should consider $$d=g(x)$$

Comment: Great "handiwork" and text to follow! +1

Comment: @amWhy: Thanks dear. :-)